# Make dynamic calculated column Formula URL open as modal

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, modal-dialog

Created a dynamic URL within a calculated column `="a href='/.../Test Doc Library/"&Title&"'>LINK</a>` which works fine, but I need it to open as a modal and cannot get it to work.

I've tried adding a button to the field in designer, I've tried adding

```
<input id="ViewButton" onclick="javascript:OpenPopUpPage(/.../Test Doc Library/"&#39;Title&#39;"');" type="button" value="View Artifacts"/>
```

but it does not seem to recognize the dynamic Title portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**

in June 2017, Microsoft disabled the use of JavaScript in a Calculated Column

That means given answers may not apply  for newer SharePoint versions

For long explanation and work arounds see:
[June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/218110#218110)

---

**Original answer:**

You are running into quoting issues because you need a **"** (***double**-quote*) to identify the SharePoint string delimiters, so can not use it inside the string.

"" (***double**-double-quote*) is the SharePoint escape notation to create a **one** **double**-quote **inside** a SharePoint string,
with the **single**-quote you then have the **two** required quoting styles required **inside** the SharePoint string to code JavaScript events.

Your Complete Calculated Column Formula becomes:

```
="<input id=""ViewButton"" 
     onclick=""javascript:OpenPopUpPage('/.../Test Doc Library/" & [Title] & "');"" 
     type=""button"" 
     value=""View Artifacts""/>"
```

Notes

- I documented it all:
- https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/#/How
- https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/#/Create
- You could swap the use of single and double-double quotes; I found this use the best readable
- The **Browser** will **add double-quotes** on Tag `attributes` at **word boundaries**, so you can use:

  ```
    ="<input id=ViewButton 
       onclick=""javascript:OpenPopUpPage('/.../Test Doc Library/" & [Title] & "');"" 
       type=button 
       value=""View Artifacts""/>"
  ```

if you had done `value=View Artifacts` it would have become:

`value="View" "Artifacts"`

- `[Title]` can be written as `Title`, because it has no spaces. I tend to use the [] notation for readability
- Always use a text-editor to prepare/edit your formulas with lots of linebreaking/indentation. Then paste to SharePoint, where SharePoint will remove all unnecessary spacing.
- Top SO-SharePoint answers that use HTML/JavaScript in Calculated Columns
  are marked with **ICC** : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=ICC

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider generating something simpler including the url, and then modify the DOM with javascript? Never used calculated columns to generate html.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try using below code...Minor changes have been done...Like (") replaced with (') and #39; is removed....

```
="<input id='ViewButton' 
         onclick='javascript:OpenPopUpPage(/.../Test Doc Library/"&Title&");' 
         type='button' 
         value='View Artifacts'/>
```